# Unable to investigate DNS poisoning between China and US

Tags: networking, dns

I am interested to know how the DNS requests to political sites differ in different countries.

I need to know how I can send a DNS query to a remote computer, let say, in China. Then, I want to compare the results to US. The goal of the experiment is to get a hand-on experience on the concept about DNS poison. I feel my lectures so theoretical.

**How can you compare DNS requests between China and US,** such that I can investigate DNS poisoning?

Comment: Can you expand on the concept of DNS poison?

Comment: Yes, the word "poisoning" is typically NOT used to refer to client-dependent answers. Poisoning is an attack againt the DNS name servers. Resolving names differently depending on the client or any other criteria is called "split DNS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a bit on how the queries are being altered. If the server is giving different results based on your locality, then asking it directly will not be of any use. If you're queries are being poisoned by a caching server in between, these methods might help.

If you have shell accounts in different parts of the world you can perform a simple test.

I'm using 'dig', which is available on most *nix systems. If you're running Windows you might want to search for an alternative [in this list of DNS tools](http://www.dns.net/dnsrd/tools.html)

**To find the responsible DNS servers**
`dig ns domain-in-question.com @the.dns.server.you.want.to.use` 
**To get the IP addres for the hostname**
`dig a host.domain-in-question.com @the.dns.server.you.want.to.use`
(You can skip the @.. part to run with your current server)

I recommend trying both of these from different parts of the world to see if the server itself is giving different results or if the caching servers on the way there are being poisoned.

Also, searching for 'how to poison dns' gave me a number of practical results.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use nslookup (the `server` command lets you specify the DNS server to ask)

Comment: nslookup is unmaintained and quite deprecated. You should use dig instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this web tool:

http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php

As for learning about DNS poisoning, every computer has settings for which DNS server to trust, and so on. If one of them in a chain is compromised, every computer downstream will receive bad information.

Answer (score 2):

If the remote servers are correctly configured, they won't let you interrogate them.

Any recursive resolver should be configured to only provide answers to the clients its intended to serve.